# How to handle database exceptions: software design

Tags: android, exception, software-design

I'm developing an Android 3.1 and above application, but this question is not specific for a particular environment.

I have three layers: activities (presentation), models (objects that represents database tables), and data (classes to access SQLite database).

All of my database methods are like this one:

```
public void insertUserAnswers(ArrayList<UserAnswer> answers)
{
    try
    {
        if ((db == null) || (!db.isOpen()))
            this.open();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        this.close();
    }
}
```

As you can see I catch every exception and I don't notify anyone about it because (and this is my problem) I don't know how to do it.

How can I notify that it was an error on a sql command? Is there any pattern to do that?

I think I can return a value to indicate that or without caching exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, do not catch all Exceptions like that, it will become difficult to know what went wrong and to notify the user of exactly what is wrong. Instead do something like this:

```
try {
    operationThatThrowsMultipleExceptions();
}
catch (ExceptionTypeOne e){
    // do something here
}
catch (ExceptionTypeTwo e){
    // do something here
}
catch (Exception e){
    // do something here
}
```

You see that we capture `Exception` right at the end, sort of a capture-all type thing to make sure that we haven't missed anything.

In terms of your model, the way I do it is to make sure that all the Data Layer objects throw their exceptions up to the presentation layer (activities) so that the activity can deal with it. At the presentation layer you can choose how to present the error to the user: usually in a nice, informative error message. This might not always be the case though. If for instance you are populating your model and hit a null pointer because there are no returns from the DB then catch the problem at the Data layer and just don't populate the model. Then when your presentation layer goes to present the model there won't be anything there and that is the point at which your presentation layer can decide how to convey that to the user.

In summary: don't catch the exceptions in the data layer unless really necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Right, sorry I did not read your question properly so changing my answer.

This really depends on what type of exceptions you are expecting, I see you quash all exceptions, but you should be able to narrow that down to specific exceptions, you could let the caller handle the exceptions, then you can show a toast or something that will help the user out if the exception is recoverable.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, if you intend to act on the error, or allow other objects to act on it (graceful degradation or so) then it seems rectified to return a suitable return value. The `insertUserAnswers` method could then return a numeric value indicating, for example:

```
0: "Success"
1: "IO error (file system not accessible or so)"
2: "SQL error (invalid insert query, invalid arguments, ...)"
```

This would perhaps require you to catch more specific exceptions than the base `Exception` in order to decide what went wrong.

Also: as a user I don't care about the technicalities about the error. I'm not even sure if I'm interested in whether there was an error or not. Hence, showing an error dialog is not necessarily "acting on the error" if you ask me. If that is the only thing you intend to do (show an error dialog) then I would suggest you not bothering with return values and skip the error notification completely.

You should always log the error in some way (either by `Log.e("MyTag", "My log message")` or your own logging infrastructure if you prefer such).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at `SQLiteOpenHelper` to open the database (once or rarely) for you. Combine with a `ContentProvider` if you want multiple processes or apps to be able to access the data.

Then make sure your code does not produce errors (on SQLite level etc) and simply let the app crash if you forgot something - that's the safest way to know you did something wrong and also allows you to get errors reported via Play / Market.

Catching exceptions is only good if there is code that you *expect* to produce errors in some cases (like file I/O) and you know how to handle them.

Catching everything will simply hide your errors and makes it hard to detect them (user would have to constantly monitor the log messages or so). If your app does not crash but is also not usable because the database is required for it to run you probably confuse the user more than just having it crash.

And to simply print the messages to logcat use

```
catch (Exception e) {
    // either 
    Log.w("TAG", e);
    // or
    Log.e("TAG", "some message", e);
}
```

That will print messages with a tag / loglevel you can choose instead of using `W/System.err`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have a specific problem that I don't know how to deal with: I connect to a web service, retrieve some data and then I will store locally. If this data is corrupted, it will cause an exception. This is not a software problem, how can I deal with? Thanks.

Comment: if the data can be corrupt (=you expect an error that is not caused by bad code) then do catch the appropriate exceptions (not all) and find a way to handle that case. E.g. check if the data you retrieved is valid and in case it is not retry (and maybe prevent the exception you get that way). If automatic error handling is impossible then inform the user that it can be tried again later if that is a possiblity. The let it crash approach is only meant for faulty code you should have fixed, not for things like network timeouts / transfer errors etc which have to be handled by your code.